# Embedded Excels in PowerPoint Issue

Tags: excel, embed, powerpoint

I am currently experiencing an issue with powerpoint 2010. I have created a three part chart in Excel and am trying to export it to powerpoint. However whenever I try to paste special the excel as an embed I am given no option to paste as an embed. It use to work seamlessly for me but I have been having this issue every time I log into powerpoint. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the data/chart you want in Excel.
Rightclick and choose Copy or pick Copy from the ribbon (Excel and PPT seem a bit wobbly when you use Ctrl+C so don't waste your time with it).

Switch to PPT, click the downward triangle under Paste, and hover over the four icons you see there.  You can choose between linking/embedding and keeping source or destination formatting.

Comment: Thats how I usually did it. For some reason I am no longer able to see this as an option.

Comment: Just to be certain here, you *are* using right-click/copy or the like and specifically *not* using Ctrl+C, correct?  If so, I don't know why you wouldn't have these options.

Comment: Yes I have tried both methods and do not have these options. Any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: Afraid not, but if it were mine, I'd be doing a repair install of Office about now.